# Bootstrap How to enable/disable input on option selected?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make form which say if Item is stockable then stock input will be enable, else stock input will be disabled.

I am looking for bootstrap shortcut if any.

Here is my code so far.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Is item stockable?</label>
  <select name="stockable" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="0">No, Item is not stockable</option>
    <option value="1">Yes, Item is stockable</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Stok</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="stock" type="text" disabled>
</div>
```

If there is no bootstrap shortcut, I hope there is simple and easy way to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a change event,toggle the disabled property based on  the value of the select using a `if`

```
$('select[name="stockable"]').change(function(){
 if($(this).val() != 0) {
 $('input[name="stock"]').prop('disabled',false);
 } else {$('input[name="stock"]').prop('disabled',true);}
});
```

or:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('select[name="stockable"]').change(function(){
   $('input[name="stock"]').prop('disabled',this.value != 0 ?false:true);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Is item stockable?</label>
  <select name="stockable" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="0">No, Item is not stockable</option>
    <option value="1">Yes, Item is stockable</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Stok</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="stock" type="text" disabled>
</div>
```

note: better go with some radio buttons here, your select has only 2 values

Answer (score 0):

Onchange event of select please check selected value is 1 then enable stock input field else disable.

In this case when no value chosen or '0' value chosen the input field will be disabled only when '1' is chosen then only it will be enabled.

Please check below snippet for better understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name='stockable']").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()==1){
      $("input[name='stock']").prop("disabled",false);
    }else{
      $("input[name='stock']").prop("disabled",true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Is item stockable?</label>
  <select name="stockable" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Choose</option>
    <option value="0">No, Item is not stockable</option>
    <option value="1">Yes, Item is stockable</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Stok</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="stock" type="text" disabled>
</div>
```